# Drawing 2 points at the beginning and the end of the LineString

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I have LineStrings in a GeoJSON files, in example:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[8.5918904,46.6325099,0],[8.5984267,46.6184961,0]]},"properties":{"name":"Pendelbahn Andermatt-Gurschen","styleUrl":"#style-Ski_Lift_Cable_Car","styleHash":null,"description":"Pendelbahn Andermatt-Gurschen (Cable Car) Capacity: people"}},

{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[8.5987235,46.6184062,0],[8.6116613,46.6022691,0]]},"properties":{"name":"Pendelbahn Gurschen-Gemsstock","styleUrl":"#style-Ski_Lift_Cable_Car","styleHash":null,"description":"Pendelbahn Gurschen-Gemsstock (Cable Car) Capacity: people"}}
```

I want to draw 2 points at the end and the beginning of the LineString. Is it possible with TileMills CartoCSS?  I don't want any modification on the GeoJSON file.

I want a line like below if it is possible:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a starting point you could use something like this:

```
#line {
  line-color:#168;

  ::lineStartMarker{
    line-width:10;
    line-cap: round;
    line-dasharray: 1,100000; // Second value greater then the line-lenght
  }
 }
```

For a end point... sorry no concrete idea.

EDIT: If you figure out the lenght of the line, then use this as second value in line-dasharray, then you also got an end point. Is there a way to get the line-lenght in tilemill?

Comment: Wonderful! how do you find out the "lineStartMarker"? I've tried to search where I can find documentation about this but I didn't find nothing. There is no result in google about this : https://www.google.co.uk/#q=lineStartMarker

Comment: actually, lineStartMarker isnt anything predefined. It is only a submodule of line. you can name it anything. It is just used to put the same geometry on top of the other one. Like this, you have the same line twice.

Comment: Sadly it doesnt work anymore: https://imgur.com/undefined